# Capturing output of process invoked through debugger

Tags: c#

I currently run my program through debugger.

```
P.FileName = "windbg.exe"
P.Arguments = "-g -G foo.exe arg1 arg2"
```

If I do redirect on process P, I dont get the output of foo.exe, How can I get the output of foo.exe to be saved to a log file and also to write to console?

Thanks.

Adding code based on comment below. But this is not what I am looking for. I need the output of foo.exe.

```
P.FileName = "windbg.exe"
P.Arguments = "-g -G foo.exe arg1 arg2"

p.RedirectOutput = true;
p.start();
StreamReader outputReader= p.StandardOutout
p.waitforexit();

string displayText = "Output" + Environment.NewLine + "==============" + Environment.NewLine;
                       displayText += outputReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.writeline(displayText);
```

Can anyone help? I havent found any solution for this...

Comment: You probably ought to consider using cdb.exe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: What advantage would I get with using cdb. Will that allow me to redirect child output to a log file?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in depth in the code project article ["How to redirect Standard Input/Output of an application"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic)

Comment: Tried this. This was similar to what I already tried. SOmehow doesnt work for me. Output stream I recive is empty. Here is the code.

Comment: In the code project article above..Process is started with the foo.exe and so the streams are avaialble. But in my case, I start the process as windbg.exe and then pass the foo.exe as an argument to execute. SO unless I am doing something wrong, this is not what I want..